# Can you close rowedit mode when showing different records in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I have a table in my Blazor view that displays records based on a selected brand from a select box. Inline table editing is also present but if you click on a record to enter rowedit mode, and you change the value in the select box to filter by another brand, the edit mode stays open and the records dont change until I exit that mode. Is there any way to work around this?

my code:

```
    <MudSelect @bind-Value="@selectedBrand" Label="Select Brand" Variant="Variant.Filled" >
            @foreach (var item in brand) {
                <MudSelectItem  Value="@item.Id">@item.Description</MudSelectItem>
            }
        </MudSelect>
    <MudTable @ref="brandPrices" Dense="true" Height="750px" Elevation="25" Items="FilteredBrands" @bind-customer="brandPrices" CanCancelEdit="@canCancelEdit"
              CommitEditTooltip="Commit Edit" OnCommitEditClick="Save" Hover="@hover" Bordered="@bordered" Striped="@striped" HorizontalScrollbar="true"
              RowEditPreview="BackupItem" RowEditCancel="ResetItemToOriginalValues" IsEditRowSwitchingBlocked="@blockSwitch" ApplyButtonPosition="@applyButtonPosition" Filter="new Func<BrandViewModel,bool>(FilterFunc)">
    
    
        <HeaderContent>    
            <MudTh Style="text-align:center" Class="pa-0"><MudTableSortLabel Style="text-align:center" SortBy="new Func<BrandViewModel, object>(x=>x.Model)">Model</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
            <MudTh Style="text-align:center" Class="pa-0"><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<BrandViewModel, object>(x=>x.Description)">Description</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>                      
        </HeaderContent>

        <RowTemplate>    
            <MudTd Style="text-align:center" Class="pa-0 mud-theme-primary" DataLabel="Model" @onclick="@(()=>Edit(@context.BrandId))">@context.Model</MudTd>

            <MudTd Class="pa-0" Style="text-align:center" DataLabel="Product Description" @onclick="@(()=>Edit(@context.BrandId))">@context.Description</MudTd>

           
        </RowTemplate>
        <RowEditingTemplate>
          
    
    
            <MudTd Style="text-align:center;" Class="pa-0 mud-theme-primary" DataLabel="Model">@context.Model</MudTd>

 <MudTd Style="text-align:center" Class="pa-0" DataLabel="Description">
                <MudTextField Style="font-weight:bold;"  @bind-Value="@context.Description" Required="true" RequiredError=""</MudTd>

        </RowEditingTemplate>
    </MudTable>

@code{
    private List<BrandViewModel> FilteredBrands => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedBrand)
        ? brandPrices.Where(s => s.Model == selectedBrand).ToList()
        : brandPrices;

// here is where I am not sure how to implement the SetEditingItem snippet

}
```

I am new to this. I apologize if I have asked this wrong, please let me know how I can improve if it is asked incorrectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your issue, you need to clear the edit mode programmatically to avoid new records not updating when you click on a different select option while edit mode is active. Update your code as follows and also check out a working example and a demo I provided below.

```
<MudTable @ref="brandPricesTable" 
          @bind-SelectedItem="selectedItem"...></MudTable>

@code {
    MudTable<BrandViewModel> brandPricesTable;
    private BrandViewModel selectedItem;

    private string _selectedBrand;
    public string selectedBrand
    {
        get => _selectedBrand;
        set
        {
            // executed whenever selection option is changed
            _selectedBrand = value;
            if (brandPricesTable is not null)
            {
                ResetItemToOriginalValues(selectedItem); // reset to original values
                brandPricesTable.SetEditingItem(null); // clear edit mode
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Online Demo Example:**

[https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wumcFEFcGxhafhCq](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GOcGFklkdxwNUdIE)

---

**Output Example:**

### [image: Output]

**Code Example:**

```
@page "/"
@inject ISnackbar Snackbar

<MudSelect @bind-Value="selectedBrand"
           Label="Select a brand"
           Variant="Variant.Outlined"
           Class="mb-5"
           Placeholder="Please Select">
    @foreach (var brand in Brands)
    {
        <MudSelectItem Value="@brand">@brand.Name</MudSelectItem>
    }
</MudSelect>

<MudTable @ref="productTable" Items="@filteredProducts"
          Hover="true" CanCancelEdit="true"
          Filter="new Func<Product, bool>(FilterFunc)"
          @bind-SelectedItem="selectedProduct"
          SortLabel="Sort By"
          CommitEditTooltip="Commit Edit"
          OnCommitEditClick="@(() => Snackbar.Add("Product edit committed"))"
          RowEditPreview="BackupItem"
          RowEditCancel="ResetItemToOriginalValues"
          RowEditCommit="ItemHasBeenCommitted"
          IsEditRowSwitchingBlocked="true">
    <ToolBarContent>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Products</MudText>
        <MudSpacer/>
        <MudTextField @bind-Value="searchString"
                      Placeholder="Search"
                      Adornment="Adornment.Start"
                      AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search"
                      IconSize="Size.Medium" Class="mt-0">
        </MudTextField>
    </ToolBarContent>

    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>
            <MudTableSortLabel InitialDirection="SortDirection.Ascending" SortBy="new Func<Product, object>(x => x.Name)">Name</MudTableSortLabel>
        </MudTh>
        <MudTh>
            <MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<Product, object>(x => x.PkgSize)">Package Size</MudTableSortLabel>
        </MudTh>
        <MudTh>
            <MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<Product, object>(x => x.Qty)">Quantity</MudTableSortLabel>
        </MudTh>
        <MudTh>
            <MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<Product, object>(x => x.Sku)">Sku</MudTableSortLabel>
        </MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Name">@context.Name</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Package Size">@context.PkgSize</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Quantity">@context.Qty</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Sku">@context.Sku</MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
    <RowEditingTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Name">
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="@context.Name" Required/>
        </MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Package Size">
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="@context.PkgSize" Required/>
        </MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Quantity">
            <MudNumericField @bind-Value="@context.Qty" Required/>
        </MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Sku">
            <MudNumericField @bind-Value="@context.Sku" Required/>
        </MudTd>
    </RowEditingTemplate>
    <PagerContent>
        <MudTablePager/>
    </PagerContent>
</MudTable>

@code {
    MudTable<Product> productTable { get; set; }
    private readonly List<string> editEvents = new();
    private string searchString = "";
    private Product selectedProduct;
    private Product elementBeforeEdit;

    private readonly List<Brand> Brands = new();
    private Brand _selectedBrand;
    public Brand selectedBrand
    {
        get => _selectedBrand;
        set
        {
            _selectedBrand = value;
            if (productTable is not null)
            {
                ResetItemToOriginalValues(selectedProduct);
                productTable.SetEditingItem(null);
            }
            filteredProducts = Products
                .Where(x => x.BrandId == value.BrandId).ToList();
        }
    }

    private readonly List<Product> Products = new();
    private List<Product> filteredProducts = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Brands.Add(new Brand("Pepsi"));
        Brands.Add(new Brand("Dr Pepper"));
        
        Products.Add(new Product("Pepsi (4/6 Packs)", "12oz can", 24, 3017, Brands[0].BrandId));
        Products.Add(new Product("Caffeine Free Pepsi", "2l bottle", 8, 3194, Brands[0].BrandId));
        Products.Add(new Product("Diet Pepsi Wild Cherry", "2l bottle", 8, 4780, Brands[0].BrandId));

        Products.Add(new Product("Diet Dr Pepper", "2l bottle", 8, 3660, Brands[1].BrandId));
        Products.Add(new Product("Diet Dr Pepper (24pk Cube)", "12oz can", 24, 19459, Brands[1].BrandId));
        Products.Add(new Product("Diet Dr Pepper (2/12 Packs)", "12oz can", 24, 84941, Brands[1].BrandId));

        selectedBrand = Brands[0];
    }

    private void AddEditionEvent(string message)
    {
        editEvents.Add(message);
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private void BackupItem(object product)
    {
        elementBeforeEdit = new Product
        {
            ProductId = ((Product)product).ProductId,
            BrandId = ((Product)product).BrandId,
            Name = ((Product)product).Name,
            PkgSize = ((Product)product).PkgSize,
            Qty = ((Product)product).Qty,
            Sku = ((Product)product).Sku
        };
        AddEditionEvent($"RowEditPreview event: made a backup of Product {((Product)product).Name}");
    }

    private void ItemHasBeenCommitted(object product)
    {
        AddEditionEvent($"RowEditCommit event: Changes to Product {((Product)product).Name} committed");
    }

    private void ResetItemToOriginalValues(object product)
    {
        ((Product)product).Name = elementBeforeEdit.Name;
        ((Product)product).PkgSize = elementBeforeEdit.PkgSize;
        ((Product)product).Qty = elementBeforeEdit.Qty;
        ((Product)product).Sku = elementBeforeEdit.Sku;
        AddEditionEvent($"RowEditCancel event: Editing of Product {((Product)product).Name} cancelled");
    }

    private bool FilterFunc(Product product)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString))
            return true;
        if (product.Name.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return true;
        if (product.PkgSize.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return true;
        if ($"{product.Qty} {product.Sku}".Contains(searchString))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public class Brand
    {
        public Brand(string name)
        {
            BrandId = Guid.NewGuid();
            Name = name;
        }

        public Guid BrandId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public Product(){}

        public Product(string name, string pkgSize, int qty, int sku, Guid brandId)
        {
            ProductId = Guid.NewGuid();
            BrandId = brandId;
            Name = name;
            PkgSize = pkgSize;
            Qty = qty;
            Sku = sku;
        }

        public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
        public Guid BrandId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PkgSize { get; set; }
        public int Qty { get; set; }
        public int Sku { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a dos not contain definition for SetEdting item error:( any idea why?

Comment: @sayef4 Did you add Table reference?

Comment: @sayef4 How did you implement it? Can you share so I can help you

Comment: yes I did. I am struggling to adapt the code snippet to fit my scenario, I will update the question :(

Comment: is it possible to just call the set editing item to the value changed of the select?

Comment: @sayef4 I have updated the answer. Do change table reference to `@ref="brandPricesTable"` and use the code that I added, if you have an issue. Let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248695/discussion-between-ibrahim-and-sayef4).

Comment: Is there a way to call the update method instead of the reset method? I get a null reference error:(